# How to replicate the "registration_id expired" scenario?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

How can we replicate the "registration_id expired" scenario, so that the GCM sends me the new canonical_id in the result? When will this case occur in realtime? Can we reproduce this scenario manually for testing? the documentation on [GCM Reference Documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#table9) says "**registration_id:** Optional string specifying the canonical registration token for the client app that the message was processed and sent to. ***Sender should use this value as the registration token for future requests. Otherwise, the messages might be rejected.***"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can invalidate a token from the server side. You may be limited to using a token that you already know is invalid.

You could try using [deleteToken](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID.html#deleteToken(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) (Android) or [deleteTokenWithAuthorizedEntity](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/ios/api/interface_g_g_l_instance_i_d.html#a4f8fde7337f07269f0f6183d191603c3) (iOS) once the token is deleted you can use it for testing invalid tokens.

Also a device requesting a new token should invalidate the currently existing token but this may have more delay than explicitly deleting.